# How do I build / get libphp5.so?

Tags: php, linux, apache2

I am running SUSE from an Amazon image which came pre loaded with apache2 and PHP. I have got my website up and running with a test index.html file, which works. When I do a index.php test my browser tries to download the file.
Now I think this is because PHP / Apache2 is not configured correctly.

The bit I *think* I need in httpd.conf is

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

I have added this block already

```
<Files *.php>
   SetOutputFilter PHP
   SetInputFilter PHP
   LimitRequestBody 9524288
</Files>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

I have installed apache2-mod_php5 via zypper with the expectation that would add libphp5.so somewhere - however I can't find it.
I have seen people mentioning it is built somehow in the installation of php / apache.
I updated Apache2 and PHP via zypper and nada.

how do I get the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module is called mod_php5.so and lives under

```
/usr/lib64/apache2/mod_php5.so
```

It's living there along with a lot of other mods, but the php5 module is not included anywhere!

So the line to add to the config (*/etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf*) is

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_php5.so
```

I also used the below command to enable the mod

```
a2enmod php
```

Also don't forget to restart Apache2 and clear your browser cache.

```
httpd2 -k -restart
```

Comment: Can't find `mod_php5.so` file under apache2 installation. Are you sure about the same?